# Program in Java for testing internet connection

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to write a simple program which tells me in real time whether I have internet connection or not. This is what I'm doing:

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class InternetConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inetAddress = "www.google.com";
        int port = 80;

        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);
                System.out.println("Connected to the internet");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Not connected to the internet");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That prints out the desired message if it reaches `www.google.com`. However, if I disconnect from the internet on purpose to check if it works, it does print "*Not connected to the internet*", then I reconnect and it shows "*Connected to the internet*", but when I disconnect again, it still shows the message "*Connected to the internet*". I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

P.S. I know this isn't the best way to check whether there's an internet connection or not.

Comment: What happens if you add a delay to the while loop (`Thread.sleep(1000);` should be fine)?  There's a chance it's trying to print too much and is stuck printing data from a few minutes previous

Comment: as soon as you connect you print the message and them you socket instance goes out of scope. Your program is done, it's not waiting around for you.

Answer (score 0):

Put a delay time after you create the socket and print the connection message.

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress,port);
    System.out.println("Connected to the internet");
}catch(Exception e){      
    System.out.println("Not connected to the internet"); 
}
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

Your program should work as intended.

Comment: Can you explain why this solves the issue? What was the reason for the problem in the first place?

Comment: Without delay, chances that the program printing data too fast that it does not reflect what the code intended to do.

Comment: It worked well. However, when applying this to a GUI (Swing), if I disconnect from the internet and run the program, I get the UnknownHostException. I don't really know how to catch this exception. I've tried: }catch (UnknownHostException e), but Eclipse underlines that in red...

Answer (score 0):

You get the UnknownHostException because if you try to connect and pull the plug, the DNS lookup for google will fail. If you got "no route to host" it should have been thrown directly too. In your code, you have no timeout-handling, you should at least use the connection timeout parameter you can supply to your Socket constructor (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) even though many problems will throw directly (more details for instance here [connect() method ignoring its timeout value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272944/connect-method-ignoring-its-timeout-value)). Also, your single runtime thread is blocked in times of trouble, it will just hang on your

```
Socket socket = new Socket(inetAddress, port);
```

and typically *there is* trouble with sockets and internet connections.. You want to be able to end execution in a controlled way perhaps too, run your program in a separate thread that you can stop in a controlled manner and probably you'd want to schedule tests rather than "just sleeping", something like

```
private final static ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ..
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                testConnections();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                // HANDLE IT
            }
        };
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, secondsInBetweenPolls, secondsInBetweenPolls, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    ..
```

Also, I would have gone for a CompletableFuture which is non-blocking and well suited for this kind of stuff - you can read about it for instance here : http://www.deadcoderising.com/java8-writing-asynchronous-code-with-completablefuture. Then the main blocks could be something like

```
private void testConnections() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    for (URL u : urls) {
        if (isRunning){
            try{
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> testConnection(u)).acceptEither(timeoutAfter(millisConnectionTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), result -> currentStatus = result).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
                    currentStatus = Result.INTERNET_UNREACHABLE;
                }
            }
            if (currentStatus.equals(Result.INTERNET_REACHED)) {
                break; // first actual internet hit is enough, right?
            }
         }
     }
     notifyListener();
     lastStatus = currentStatus;
}

private void notifyListener() {
    if (lastStatus == null || !currentStatus.equals(lastStatus)) {
        if (currentStatus.equals(Result.INTERNET_REACHED)) {
            listener.connectionIsUp();
        } else {
            listener.connectionIsDown();
        }
    }
}

private Result testConnection(URL url) {
    if (isRunning) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnect = null;
        try {
            urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(millisConnectionTimeOut);
            int resultCode = urlConnect.getResponseCode();
            if (resultCode == 200) {
               return Result.INTERNET_REACHED;
            }
         } catch (IOException ignore) {}
     } finally {
             if (urlConnect != null) {
                 urlConnect.disconnect();
             }
         }
    }
    return Result.INTERNET_UNREACHABLE;
}
```

Comment: what is timeoutAfter ?

Comment: it indicates the time at which this CompleteableFuture will timeout; which is an accepted outcome.

Comment: ..it's not obvious but in my example it took shapes of a CompletableFuture. you can always make use of "anything" that times out using CompletableFuture **(WHY can you not add multiple line code in comments...)** Anyway, you can fetch the complete example I tried out at

[internet.tar.gz](https://www.nollettnoll.net/internet.tar.gz)

if you'd like.

Comment: What is the purpose of the isRunning attribute ?

Comment: I hooked this stuff into some tray icon code I had laying around so that there was a main gui thread running and managing the tester thread; the gui registered itself as a listener - it would flip the icon when I pulled the plug, flip back when internet was back, etc. The boolean and the shutdown hook was just to tell the tester thread to stop executing and making sure it would die. (so initially there was no main method included. and on line 82 there should be a testConnections(); too).